# Crystal Reports Loading Database info

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

I have SAP Crystal Reports 2011 and use it to edit reports we use with JobBOSS ERP system.  These reports were all put in place before I started here and am just now learning Crystal Reports.  I am trying to edit the reports but am having issues.

So when I open the report in Crystal Reports the Field Explorer is showing that the file being used to pull fields into the reports is a TTX file.  I know nothing about TTX files and assumed I could just find the data in my tables and import it in but apparently that wont mix well from what I am understanding.  I have no clue what to do with the TTX and being able to populate the fields on the page with data from another table.

Where do I start with this?  All of my forms use the TTX to pull data.  Does anyone have any resources that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

To change this report, you must use the report version in the JobBoss production report folder (.rpt).  Save the .rpt to a work area.  Make changes and then place back in the folder retrieved from.  You can add tables to this kind of report but cannot change the .ttx table. The report must be run from within Jobboss.  Save the original .rpt to a save folder first.  Call with questions.